# Организация сжатия изображений на сервере

Tags: php, сжатие

Необходимо оптимизировать изображения на сайте крупного интернет-магазина. Задача состоит в том, чтобы размер изображений уменьшился без потери качества. Оптимизация должна проходить на стороне сервера. Основые вопросы:

1. Какие инструменты сжатия лучше всего использовать? Важными параметрами выбранного инструмента является: производительность (процессор, память, время выполнения), влияние на размер, поддерживаесый формат (png/jpg).
2. Как лучше всего организовать сжатие: сразу после загрузки изображения, либо, например, по крону - целой папки с изображениями с определенной переодичностью запуска.

В настоящий момент присматриваюсь к инструментам, описанным в https://compressor.io/about

Comment: Ну как, Вы нашли оптимальное решение??

Answer (score -1):

Можно повесить watcher, который будет следить за появлением новых изображений в директории и сжимать их.

Например [**этот**](https://github.com/OrlovEvgeny/TinyJPG).